# Tinyint vs varchar to identify types of entities

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

We're going to use a table to include sort of different entities which have most fields in common (i.e. ***"order", "invoice", "estimate", "dispatch"***...). We decided to have them all in the same table for some reasons, but this is not the question.

This table will have a special field which will hold the identifier of the entity. We've been using varchars in the past, like the ones described above.

Would it be recommendable to use a tinyint instead, so that 0 means "order", 1 means "estimate" and so on?

Comment: Actually sounds like ENUM is the way to go if I understand your question correctly. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Comment: I'm not sure if I should use ENUM. Some people say avoid ENUM and SET at all costs.

Comment: use a char or tiny int, and make it a foreign key to a new table where you store the varchar description: "order", "invoice", "estimate", "dispatch"...

Comment: That's a point, but it means one more join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your goal is.

**For performance:**

1. tinyint uses less space, so it would be better if you wanted to save space
2. queries could become faster

**For readability (by db users with less experience)**

*Keep using varchar*

Comment: Would they have the same performance if I add this field as an INDEX?

Comment: If you are just selecting the value then it doesn't matter.

But if you are using it in a where condition then the performance will be better using an int.

Comment: `ENUM` (up to 255 options) takes only 1 byte.  `ENUM` displays a string, without having to do a lookup.